# Fastest Way to Solve TSP optimally

Tags: cplex

I have found an interesting approach for solving the traveling salesman problem in IBM CPlex examples. The algorithm adds the subtour constraints to the problem whenever needed and solves the problem again with the new constraints. This is an iterative process. I just want to know if this is the fastest way to deal with large TSP instances or not? Do anyone have any reference regarding the fastest way to solve TSP optimally?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much the fastest way for larger TSP instances. Look up the Concorde TSP solver which I believe uses this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Branch and Cut, using min cut auxiliary problems as a means of idnetifying violated subtour constraints, could also be a fast approach. There is no "perfect" way...

Reference:
John E., Mitchell (2002). "Branch-and-Cut Algorithms for Combinatorial Optimization Problems". Handbook of Applied Optimization: 65–77.